# Play a downloaded video with flask

Tags: python, web, flask, static-files, pafy

I have a simple flask server. I downloaded, using pafy, a video from a youtube link provided by the user.

```
@app.route('/')
def download():
    return render_template('basic.html')
```

The basic.html template has a form that submits an action to download:

```
<form action="download_vid" method="post">
Link: <input type="text" name="download_path"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have another end point, /download_vid that looks like this.

```
@app.route('/download_vid', methods=['POST'])
def download_vid():
    url = request.form['download_path']
    v = pafy.new(url)
    s = v.allstreams[len(v.allstreams)-1]
    filename = s.download("static/test.mp4")
    return redirect(url_for('done'))
```

The desired link is indeed downloaded as a .mp4 file in my static folder. I can watch it and I can also use it as a source for a  tag in an HTML file, if I open it locally.

```
@app.route('/done')
def done():
    return app.send_static_file('test.mp4')
```

From what I understand, 'send_static_file' serves files from the static directory. However, I get a 404 error when I run the server, even though the video is clearly there.

I have also tried a different version for done():

```
@app.route('/done')
def done():
    return return render_template('vid.html')
```

Here, vid.html resides in templates and has a hard coded path to static/test.mp4. It is loaded after the download is complete. I do not have a 404 error in this case, but the  tag don't do anything, it's just gray. If I open vid.html locally (double click on it), it works, it shows the video.

Can you please help me understand what is going on?

What I want to achieve is this:

1. Take an input from the user [ Done ]
2. Use that input to download a video [ Done ]
3. Serve that video back to the user [ ??? ]

Answer (score 4):

I think you have something going on with file paths or file permissions.

- Is the video being downloaded into `static` directory?
- Is the `static` directory in the same directory, along with your `main.py` file?
- Does your flask app have permissions to read the file?

I think the reason your file did not load in html template is because you referenced it as `static/test.mp4` from an url - `/done` which translates the video path to be `/done/static/test.mp4`.

Instead of trying to push the file using Flask, you can redirect to the actual media file.

```
@app.route('/done')
def done():
    return redirect('/static/test.mp4')
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. Yes, the video is being downloaded to static. Yes, static is in the same directory as my main.py ( I call it routes.py ). Yes, it has permission. Since it can write there, I assume it can also read. To be sure, I run the server with sudo. Still, no result. I also tried: app.send_static_file(url_for('static', filename=''test.mp4''))

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I get this error: Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.   The file is clearly there. And it's working.